# How to disable scaling percentage box in visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How to disable the following box from settings in visual studio? It is a small window in the lower left corner above the status bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is impossible to do through the available options.

You can use the extension written by Noah Richards, a visual studio platform developer, to disables the mouse scroll zooming

http://blogs.msdn.com/noahric/archive/2010/03/18/disabling-mouse-wheel-zoom-through-ieditoroptions.aspx

Edit: The post is old, but the concept is valid, and the extension is available to download via Visual Studio:

[Extension in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yGP6.png)

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NoahRichards.DisableMouseWheelZoom

Comment: the post is too old